# How to create a PowerPoint from scratch with Apache POI?

Tags: apache-poi, apache-poi-4

I can't seem to create a PPT like this. Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{            
File file=new File("/Users/Rakuten/Desktop/Test/example2.ppt");
    try {
    FileOutputStream out= new FileOutputStream(file);
    SlideShowFactory.create(file);
    out.close();
    } 
catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println(e);
    }   

        }
```

Comment: https://poi.apache.org/components/slideshow/how-to-shapes.html#NewPresentation

Comment: Doesn't help as this is for previous versions of POI.

Comment: Constructors of [HSLFSlideShow](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/dev/org/apache/poi/hslf/usermodel/HSLFSlideShow.html) of current version. [SlideShowFactory](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/dev/org/apache/poi/sl/usermodel/SlideShowFactory.html) is only for creating `SlideShow`s from files having ppt data already stored. And even if your `example2.ppt` would contain ppt data already, your code does not even doing something with the `SlideShow` gotten from `SlideShowFactory`. Or where do you think it does?